# igraph Failed to install through pip

Tags: igraph

Igraph failed to install through pip install python-igraph
[image: First Error that is shown: Failed building wheel for python-igraph]

[image: failed to install]

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu Users :

Python-igraph requires build-essential and python-dev dependencies.

Installing python-igraph through apt-get

Add the repository of igraph to apt:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:igraph/ppa
```

Then update and install the python-igraph package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-igraph
```

Comment: I ran this, but when I tried to run a python file using igraph, I got the igraph not installed error

Answer (score 4):

Some additional notes for ubuntu (16.04) users, (python 3.6)

I ran in to the same issue.
For those of you who might have missed it. The complete list of dependencies are a bit longer than stated here. The list should be as stated in the [readme](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph)

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev
```

this made it possible to install in a virtual environment through `pip` without adding the ppa (which failed for me with a 404 error).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with igraph's `setup.py` on Windows. *Theoretically* you could work around this by downloading the source code of `python-igraph` from PyPI, extracting it manually and then running:

```
python setup.py install --no-wait
```

However, note that the only code path where you can hit the above error in `setup.py` is when the installer determines that you do not have the C core of igraph installed on the system (or the installer is not able to find it). Since `python-igraph` is just an *interface* to the igraph library, you won't be able to compile it from source if you don't have the C library itself. Therefore, it is better to use the pre-compiled installers of `python-igraph` from [Christoph Gohlke's page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-igraph).

Answer (score 0):

igraph is now jgraph.   From the **init**,

"DeprecationWarning("To avoid name collision with the igraph project, "
                         "this visualization library has been renamed to "
                         "'jgraph'. Please upgrade when convenient.")
"

Check your version, you might want 0.7.1 not 0.1.11 which is **completely different**.

0.7.1 [may not install on Windows](https://igraph.org/python/) via pip. Download it from  [Christoph Gohlke's page](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), then install the download with pip.

Credit to @Tamas answer found here:
[here](http://foo.com)